# Running Electron directly (electron app.js) vs. running from package.json script (npm run electron)

Tags: node.js, npm, electron

I have a simple Electron tray app with the following source:

```
const { app, Tray, Notification, Menu, nativeImage } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');

const iconPath = path.join(__dirname, 'assets/icons/iconTemplate.png');

let tray = null;

app.whenReady().then(() => {
    try {
        console.log(iconPath);
        tray = new Tray(nativeImage.createFromPath(iconPath));
        tray.setToolTip('Electron app');
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
})
```

Here's the `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "Electron app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "electron": "electron app.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "package-linux": "electron-packager . --overwrite --icon=assets/icons/256x256.png --out=release-builds",
    "deb64": "electron-installer-debian --config config/build-config.json"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
  }
}
```

[image]

When I run the app with `electron app.js`, nothing happens. But when I run `npm run electron` (which runs the script from package.json) the app works. **What's the difference**?

Comment: Could you possibly add your `package.json` to this post? May be helpful in assessing the scripts.

Comment: what is `main` on your package.json and have you installed `electron` globally?

Comment: @AlecBreton I have added `package.json`. @Yanikus Yes, I have installed electron globally and `main` points to `app.js` (directory structure posted).